# Find the closure of A∩B

Tags: real-analysis

I have  two sets, $A= \{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$. $A \cap B = \{2 \}$. The definition of closure states, the closure of any set A is the smallest set that contains A. So I do not know how to use this to determine the closure of (A∩B)

Comment: You can look again the definition, what it says?

Comment: The closure of any set A, is the smallest closed set that contains A. By this definition, the empty set is the only other set contained in A. And the empty set is closed. So the closure of {2} must be the empty set

Comment: No, you need a closed set containing $A$; the empty set does not contain $A$, instead it is contained in $A$. Singletons are closed in a Hausdorff space, so $\{ 2\}$ is a closed set. If a set it closed, then it equals its closure.

Comment: Where are these sets ? I don't think it makes sense to talk about closure without knowing what topology we are considering ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your defnition the closure of a set $A$ $cl(A)$ is the smallest closed set $B$ which contains $A$.
Now a singleton set is closed. Therefore $\{2\}$ is smallest closed set which contains $\{2\}$.Hence $cl\{2\}=\{2\}$

Answer (score 0):

The closure of $\{2\}$ is the smallest closed set containing $\{2\}$. That is, if $S \supseteq \{2\}$ is closed, $S \supseteq \{2\}^-$.

so what is $\{2\}^-$?

Answer (score -1):

Closure is the set $\overline{A}$ such that $\forall a\in \overline{A}$: $a\cap A$ is not empty.

The closure of a single point would be that point itself, as it is the only point that always has a nonzero intersect with set described by that point!

Comment: If $A=(1,2)$, then $\bar{A} = [1,2]$ and $a= 1 \in \bar{A}$ however, $\{a\} \cap A = \emptyset$. Note that $a \cap A$ is nonsense.